# PHP, помощь с массивом

Tags: php, массивы, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Здравствуйте. У меня была проблема: выполнялось 20 запросов к api vk:

```
$select_info = "SELECT a_id, post_id, date, admin FROM vk_post ORDER BY post_id DESC";

 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_info);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$get_adm_name = $VkApi->api("users.get", [
    "access_token" => ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "user_ids" => $row["admin"]
]);

$admin = $get_adm_name["response"][0]["first_name"] . " ". $get_adm_name["response"][0]["last_name"];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$row["a_id"]?></td>
    <td><?=$row["date"]?></td>
    <td><a href="<?="https://vk.com/wall-26363301_" . $row["post_id"];?>">This</a></td>
    <td><?=$admin?></td>
</tr>
```

Это не есть хорошо, и мне посоветовали сделать массив за пределами цикла и работать с ним:

```
$admin_id = [
1id => "1AdminName",
2id => "2AdminName",
3id => "3AdminName"
```

];

Но не пойму как. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вынести все ID за предел цикла и сделать 1 запрос к ВК

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_info);

$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) $admins_id[] = $row["admin"];


$get_adm_names = $VkApi->api("users.get", [
"access_token" => ACCESS_TOKEN,
"user_ids" => implode(',', $admins_id)
]);

?>
```

Думаю идея ясна

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое с:

Comment: `$ids = array_unique(array_column($rows, 'admin'))`

Comment: @teran, к чему это?

Comment: @Біпач к тому, что не надо писать `foreach ($rows as $row) $admins_id[] ` чтобы получить колонку значений, которые еще и с повторами будут